# When is "raise Class, instance" useful?

Tags: python

If you have an exception instance, why would you need to specify its class?

What's the advantage over simply `raise instance`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no advantage. `raise Class, instance` is a legacy expression and is [completely equivalent](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#raise) to `raise instance`. Especially, the first notation is [removed in Python 3 and replaced by the latter](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/2to3.html#2to3fixer-raise).

Comment: Not exactly equivalent — see my answer. Equivalence must have been the intent, but funny side effects also ensued.

Answer (score 2):

There's no reason ever to use it really. It's archaic usage from back before exceptions had to be class instances, and it's gone in Python 3.

Comment: Should the tutorial be updated to say that this is deprecated? How/where should I submit such a suggestion?

Comment: If the tutorial actually uses this feature I'd call that a doc bug and submit through the normal bug tracker. I can't immediately see any example of that, though...

Answer (score 1):

You can pass one exception for another:

```
exc = StopIteration('Iterator has already exhaused!')
try:
  raise ValueError, exc
except ValueError, e:
  print e.args[0]
```

Good practical uses of this still elude me, though there must be some.

Comment: This is still identical to `raise ValueError(StopIteration('Iterator has already exhaused!'))`. `e` is a `ValueError` and the `StopException` is only an argument to that constructor.